# db2 expired password but cannot reset

Tags: linux, db2, authentication, db2-luw

Has anybody encountered this problem with a db2 server? I'm running a development database and connecting to the database gives me a password expired error. Trying to reset it will give me an invalid username/password error.

```
$ db2 connect to mydb user devuser using mypassword
SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "1" ("PASSWORD EXPIRED").  
SQLSTATE=08001
$ db2 connect to mydb user devuser using mypassword new newpasswd confirm newpasswd
SQL30083N  Attempt to change password for user id "devuser" failed with 
security reason "24" ("USERNAME AND/OR PASSWORD INVALID").  SQLSTATE=08001
```

Everything I've read says that I should reset the password but I can't due to the invalid username/password error.

I don't get this error when connecting using the db2 admin user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0021804.html

> User authentication is completed by a security facility outside the Db2 database system, through an authentication security plug-in module. A default authentication security plug-in module that relies on operating-system-based authentication is included when you install the Db2 database system

If the reset password feature of the CLP is not working for you, you should reset the password directly on the operating-system at the server (or on the security system (e.g. LDAP) that Db2 has been configured to use)

Comment: Resetting the user's password at OS level worked. Thanks! I didn't realize that at first because I am able to log in to OS using the current password. But I guess I still had to reset it. This is a freshly installed DB2 by the way but the OS user already exists prior to DB2 installation.

Comment: If you are on Docker, you need to perform a "docker exec" into the DB2 container and then change the password for the local user that you are trying to login to DB2 with. In my case, the name of the user was "myuser". I changed the password by executing `passwd myuser`. Note that you are root by default when you exec into the container. Else use `docker exec -u root ...`.